# PHP, Server-Sent Events - date_default_timezone_get() does not work properly in remote file

Tags: javascript, php, datetime

I am using server-sent events, and trying to display times according to the local time of the viewer.

All times in my databases are stored as GMT, in `DATETIME` fields:

*Code Block 1*

```
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO...');
$stmt->execute(array($now));
```

And then the reverse (probably more complicated than it needs to be):

*Code Block 2*

```
$utimezone = date_default_timezone_get();
$then = date($row['ndate']);
$date = date_create($then);
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($utimezone));
$nDate = date_format($date, 'd M \'y (g:i A)');
```

This all works properly, when the window is live in the browser, but falls apart when `date_default_timezone_get()` is in a remotely-called file:

*JavaScript*

*Code Block 3*

```
var src = new EventSource('sse_bot.php?uid=' + userID);
```

where the `date_default_timezone_get()` is in the `sse_bot.php` file.

I tried setting a session variable from the browser window:

*Code Block 4*

```
$utimezone = date_default_timezone_get();
$_SESSION['tzone'] = $utimezone;
```

and then using it in the `sse_bot.php` file:

*Code Block 5*

```
$utimezone = $_SESSION['tzone'];
```

But no dice.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT 1**

I echoed it back, and `$utimezone = $_SESSION['tzone'];` *does* set it to the appropriate value ('America/Denver' in my case). But it seems that the issue is, specifically, with the line:

*Code Block 6*

```
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($utimezone));
```

When I use *Code Block 2* through a browser, it works perfectly. I can even change the line to:

*Code Block 7*

```
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Denver'));
```

And all is well.

Making the identical change to the `sse_bot.php` file has no effect. The time returned, after all the slight-of-hand, is identical to the time that went in to it.

Comment: FWIW: For future reference, always store as UTC and convert from there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the timezone was already 'America/Denver', because I hadn't set it otherwise. In the browser version, it is set elsewhere, but in the `sse_bot.php`, it wasn't.

Just need to add:

```
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
```

somewhere preceding *Code Block 6*, and Bob's your auntie.

(Probably not answer-worthy, and better suited to a comment, butfuture stumblers will more readily find this one.)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the point here I think. All PHP runs on the server and so will always reflect the server's version of timezone - that is the expected behaviour in every case. If you want to find the client's timezone then you need to query in Javascript and send the reported value back to the server.

Comment: Please see my answer. PHP is happy to do the time conversions, so long as the appropriate identifiers are set. In my case, I neglected to set the current timezone to GMT